# Python: How do you get a portion of a text from another app into a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm trying to make an email reader, but I'm stuck because I don't know how to read text off an app. How do I do it? I'm on a Win10 PC and I use the 'Mail' app for email.
this is some quick pseudocode:

```
email = get.email.from.app()
print(email)
```

Comment: What Mail does is download your email from the server that stores them using some API then does a bunch to that raw text to make it look nice on your screen. I doubt that the Mail app exposes a nice and easy way for you to get the raw email data like that. What you should probably do is find what API the Mail app uses and see if you can use it as well.

Comment: I think the best You can TRY is to get to the database where this app stores all emails and TRY reading from there (tho I think those files may be encrypted). another interesting approach would be to open the app, simulate user input and get to the mail, then take a screenshot and convert screenshot to text (for that You could use `pyautogui`)

Comment: This is going to be a lot more complicated than you think. There are libraries out there for interacting with certain apps/APIs but generally will require much more experience to work with them. For example, with a quick search on the internet, I found a library for Gmail: https://pypi.org/project/gmail/

Comment: you will need to to use `imaplib`, and connect to the email server directly or `pyautogui` if you have no choice, as @Matiiss said

Comment: working with other applications can be very big problem. For emails I would read them directly from server using standard module [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) or (simpler) external module like [imapclient](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/) or [imbox](https://github.com/martinrusev/imbox)